# live update google charts php+js

Tags: php, ajax, google-visualization

I have candlestick chart drawn with googlecarts api.
But i can't do the live updating for it.

Next code is html part of my chart visualisation:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function drawV(){
  var a = $.ajax({
  url: "_ajax3.php",
  dataType:"html",
  async: false
  }).responseText;
  console.log(a);

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([a],true);

  options = {
    chartArea:{
      left: 55,
      top: 40,
      width: 760,
      height: 210
    },
    candlestick:{
      fallingColor:{
        fill: "#41a6ef",
        stroke: "#41a6ef",
        strokeWidth: 1
      },
      risingColor:{
        fill: "#f01717",
        stroke: "#f01717",
        strokeWidth: 1
      },
      hollowIsRising: true
    },
    series: {0: {type: "candlesticks"}, 1: {type: "line", targetAxisIndex:1, color:"#91d6ff"}},
    legend:"none"
  };
  chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById("chart_div"));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawV);

setInterval(function(){
  drawV();
}, 10000);
</script>

<div id='chart_div'></div>
```

I dont sure in ajax dataType, but anyway, in worked case 'var data =...' line looks like that:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([["18:26",20.79102,20.79102,20.79102,20.79102,20.79102],["18:27",20.79102,20.85,20.79102,20.85,20.82051],["18:28",20.85,20.8583,20.85,20.8583,20.85415],
["18:26",20.79102,20.79102,20.79102,20.79102,20.79102]],true);
```

And ajax return the same data (without highlevel [ ]).

```
["18:26",20.79102,20.79102,20.79102,20.79102,20.79102],["18:27",20.79102,20.85,20.79102,20.85,20.82051],["18:28",20.85,20.8583,20.85,20.8583,20.85415],
["18:26",20.79102,20.79102,20.79102,20.79102,20.79102]
```

How can i get it works?
EDIT: now i get the next java error:`Uncaught Error: Not a valid 2D array.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your AJAX call is returning a string that is not valid JSON.  Modify your server code to add `[` and `]` to the ends of the string, then use this to create the DataTable:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(JSON.parse(a),true);
```

Comment: I've just found this solution an do it myself! =) Thank you!